# Is it possible to enter start/stop points non-interactively in Road Graph plugin?

Tags: qgis, plugins

I need to find the shortest paths in a network of roads for many pairs of start/stop points?  The **Road Graph** plugin in QGIS allows me to interactively select a starting and ending point on a map, but I can't do this interactively with hundreds of such points.  Is there a way to run this plugin in a non-interactive way?